# Specify next boot to be into Safe Mode/WinRE via command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, boot, safe-mode

As the title says I would like a script that tells Windows that the next boot should be into Safe Mode or at least that the <kbd>F8</kbd> menu should be presented on next boot.

Booting into WinRE (*Launch startup repair...*) is probably even more un-doable.

I looked over bcdedit options but didn't see anything like this. I know `msconfig` has an option for Safe Boot but it's GUI only.

Currently if I want to boot into Safe Mode or launch WinRE then I have to forcefully restart my PC first for those options to be presented during boot (<kbd>F8</kbd> does not bring up the Safe Mode option under normal conditions).

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: F8 does work, but there's only about a half-second window, so you have to really hammer the key to get it to show. Not fun. But a direct answer below...

Answer (score 3):

`bcdedit /default <id>` is how you force it to boot into a non-default partition. Use `bcdedit` to list them and select the identifier you want. To force the current OS into safe mode at next startup, `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network`.

Remember to undo all of this afterward; it might be safer to follow the directions [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/a32711fd-7cc6-4fff-bb95-150edd5dc862) and create a new id for the safemode option, so that it's easy to switch back.

Comment: Intresting.I will defenetly look into this.

Comment: Ok the code above worked.To disable i used this: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot

Comment: Still have problem not able to boot winre but perhaps found something: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/installation2/q-how-can-i-add-a-microsoft-windows-imaging-format-wim-based-preinstallation-environment-pe-and-recovery-environment-re-to-my-boot-menu-.aspx