# Boot the PC directlly into WindowsRecovery environment?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, bootloader

I know the way to restart the PC to boot directlly into "Safe Mode" using bcdedit command like this:

```
bcdedit.exe /set {current} safeboot minimal
```

But there is a way (using bcdedit or don't) to restart the PC to boot directlly into the **WinRE** environment options (the blue screen of Windows 8 with recovery options)?

PS: I need to automate the task, when the user is logged in the account I would like to restart the PC to go to the **WinRE** menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the boot options by opening up a "Run..." prompt (WindowsKey + R) and typing "msconfig" and pressing enter.

On the boot tab, you can select safeboot + minimal. As far as automating the task, You can probably manage the local machine's policy to execute a .bat on startup that runs the bcdedit command that you have originally posted.

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking how to boot into WindowsRecovery environment (the blue screen of Windows 8 with recovery options), not into Safe Mode. here is something similar question with the WinRE part of the question unsolved: http://superuser.com/questions/230437/specify-next-boot-to-be-into-safe-mode-winre-via-commandline